# "Unclosed quotation mark" error using entity framework

Tags: entity-framework

I'm trying to create DB using code first with entity framework.

When I do this:

```
myDbContext.DataBase.Create();
```

I'm getting this exception message:

"Unclosed quatation mark after the character  string '(' "

Any idea?

Comment: you should include the full stack trace

Comment: Have a look at `((IObjectContextAdapter)myDbContext).ObjectContext.CreateDatabaseScript()` and see if anything looks strange.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that somewhere in the data that you are loading when you create the database that one of the strings you're trying to insert has an apostrophe in it. You could Check through the any data that my be called during the Initializer and comment it out in sections until you find which record(s) may be causing the offending message.